# Installing a deb file build with checkinstall on Ubuntu into a docker container based on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dpkg, deb, checkinstall

I have compiled a C++ software on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, and used `checkinstall` to install it. This build the corresponding `.deb` file and that's nice.

But now I want to install that `.deb` file into a docker container based on "Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" and `dpkg` shows this error:

```
# dpkg --install mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb 
dpkg-deb: error: archive 'mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb
```

How could I install this `.deb` file into my container without having to compile the software *again* (which will mean installing all the C++ building tools into my container, which I want to avoid...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dpkg` in Debian [doesn’t support `zstd` compression](https://bugs.debian.org/892664). To be able to even extract your package in Debian, you need to convert it:

- extract its components:

  ```
  ar -x mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb
  ```
- decompress them:

  ```
  zstd -d control.tar.zst
  zstd -d data.tar.zst
  ```
- recompress them:

  ```
  xz control.tar
  xz data.tar
  ```
- re-create your package:

  ```
  rm mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb 
  ar -rc mypackage-8.0.0_20221030-1_amd64.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
  ```

This will produce a package which Debian’s `dpkg` can at least attempt to process. Since your package was built on Ubuntu 22.04, you’re liable to run into dependency problems.

For best results, you should really build the package on the platform you want to run it on. In your case, that means either using `ubuntu:22.04` as your container’s base image, or rebuilding your package in a Debian 11 container.